# gae error:AttributeError

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

When i try deploying. GAE gives me to following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\appcfg.py", line 127, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Projects\appcfg.py", line 123, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Projects\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5401, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Projects\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5392, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Projects\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2864, in __init__
    action.options(self, self.parser)
  File "C:\Projects\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3926, in _UpdateOptions
    if JavaSupported():
  File "C:\Projects\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 250, in JavaSupported
    tools_java_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(appcfg_java.__file__), 'java')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__file__'
2014-11-30 11:39:45 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Please help me to fix it..(PS: It is a PHP deployment)

**UPDATE:**
My app.yaml content as asked, i have uploaded earlier with the similar app.yaml it had worked..

```
application: project-name
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /main.js
  script: main.js

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Comment: I think this means that you are using a version of Python earlier than 2.7. What is the output of:
python -V
?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in appcfg when running on versions of Python earlier than 2.7. If you are not easily able to update to 2.7, you could patch appcfg.py (the path is shown in your stack trace). The line where you are getting an exception is this one:

```
tools_java_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(appcfg_java.__file__), 'java')
```

You could change it to insert this line immediately before:

```
if not appcfg_java: return False
```

Because this is Python you need to be careful about indentation. The new line should have exactly the same indentation as the existing line shown here.